# select from URL in snowflake

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i have a json file. how cane i call this json file from url?

i have this json file ([https://github.com/mehdimarjan/optimism-overtime-markets/blob/main/games.json'](https://github.com/mehdimarjan/optimism-overtime-markets/blob/main/games.json%27)).
i wanna select from this url.

i tried to use `SELECT parse_url('https://github.com/mehdimarjan/optimism-overtime-markets/blob/main/games.json')` but only shown this.

```
{
  "fragment": null,
  "host": "github.com",
  "parameters": null,
  "path": "mehdimarjan/optimism-overtime-markets/blob/main/games.json",
  "port": null,
  "query": null,
  "scheme": "https"
}
```

Comment: If you want to query data in Snowflake then you need to physically bring it into Snowflake or reference it via an External table or Stage. Otherwise you could probably write something in Snowpark to pull the data via this URL and process it. You can't just pull data in from a URL in a SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

In general Snowflake does not "go out a fetch data", you use it to mostly pulling from blob stores, at which point the [Load Data into Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/guides-overview-loading-data) doc's will be your best bet.

If you have one just a one off data loading task, like this file seems to cover, you can download the file and then [Loading Data Using the Web Interface](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-web-ui) might cover all that you need.